# ImageView Image disappear when something gets redrawn

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a TextView and an ImageView in a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="72sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instructionView"
        android:layout_width="245sp"
        android:layout_height="70sp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView 
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:id="@+id/ma_landmarkView"
        android:layout_width="70sp"
        android:layout_height="70sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my Code, I set different Images to the ImageView (All 68x68 pixels size) with

```
myView.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.mypicture));
```

The Problem is now, the Image is no more seen if the TextView gets other Text by .setText(...) and redraws itself. The Image also dissappears if other Views outside this LinearLayout change their size and get redrawn (e.g. an MapView that has been zoomed in/out). 
If I set all .setText(...) from this TextView in comments //, the picture from the ImageView stays visible and doesn't disappear anymore. 
But I don't want to go without that TextView... 
I already hardcoded the Views heights and widths but that does not help.

Any Ideas ?

**EDIT:** 
I just saw at testing, that by setting different Text to the TextView it can get a bigger width (even bigger than I stated in the *xml) if this TextView gets too width, the Image disappears. Maybe a work around solution works, that prevents the TextView from getting too width. Some1 knows how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try .setBackgroundDrawable instead

Comment: okay, but problem still exists: Once the TextView resizes itself, the Image disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the different view's units to dp instead of sp. sp is usually used for the actual text size. So basically change the layout_width and layout_height to use dp units, and keep the textSize in sp units.

Please change these and re-run your application, and let me know if this changed the results. If it doesn't work, add some of your java code so I can better tell where the issue is.

Comment: at first I had "dp" but I saw in the Log the sizes of the TextView changing temporarly when changing the text, so I used "sp" to see if I get another behaviour. I didn't. But now I just use .setBackgroundDrawable again after every change of the textView and it works for me. Though I'ld get memory problems in order to changing the textView nearly continuosly, but it's fine.